# What is wrong with my solution?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, assignment-operator

*This is translation from my native language.* 

You have a class:

```
class Boo : public SuperBoo {
  Foo* fFoo1;
  Foo* fFoo2;
}
```

Where Foo - monomorphic class and Boo owns pointers fFoo1, fFoo2. 
Overload assign operator for Boo.

My solution was:

```
class Foo
{
public:
    Foo()
    {}
};

class SuperBoo
{
public:
    virtual ~SuperBoo()
    {}
};

class Boo : public SuperBoo
{
public:
    Boo(const int f1_id, const int f2_id)
    {
        f1 = new Foo(f1_id);
        f2 = new Foo(f2_id);
    }
    ~Boo()
    {
        delete f1;
        delete f2;
    }
    /* C++11 only
    Boo(Boo&& other)
    {
        std::swap(*this, other);
    }
    */
    Boo(const Boo& other)
    {
        f1 = new Foo(*(other.f1));
        f2 = new Foo(*(other.f2));
    }
    Boo& operator=(Boo other)
    {
        std::swap(f1, other.f1);
        std::swap(f2, other.f2);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Foo* f1;
    Foo* f2;
};
```

But employer didnt like it. What is wrong here? Thanks for help.

Comment: For one, it is not exception safe.

Comment: Agree, that i will lose pointers if new throw

Comment: There's a good solution for this problem of exception safety: use one of the built-in [smart pointer classes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer#C.2B.2B_smart_pointers) that use the RAII idiom to solve the memory leak problem for you.

Comment: @Cody Gray yes better to use smart pointers but i think that test is not to use them.

Comment: Then that's a stupid test. You would never write actual C++ code that didn't use smart pointers. If the built-in classes weren't available (??), then you would write a simple one of your own. The RAII idiom is truly *fundamental* C++. You don't deal with memory leaks with a mess of code in every single method.

Comment: @Cody Gray Agree with you

Answer (score 1):

The constructor could be rewritten as:

```
Boo(const int f1_id, const int f2_id)
{
    std::unique_ptr<Foo> pf1 = new Foo(f1_id);
    f2 = new Foo(f2_id);

    f1 = pf1.release();
}
```

This way if f2 constructor throws, f1 won't be leaked.

The copy constructor should follow the same rule by the way.